# Running backdated transaction in Corda

Tags: corda

I have a scheduled state, which invokes scheduled activity. As per states generated and logs, we found scheduler activity stops because of breaking errors and now new state has been created after it. Is it possible to run the scheduler back from the day it stopped. Is it possible to run a flow on a backdate in Corda, given we have access to all the nodes and network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to run the scheduler in a backdated way, e.g. by changing the system clock.

To understand why we need to understand how the scheduler in Corda works.

The scheduling system doesn't loop over the system time to work out when it should run, but instead kicks off the activity once a particular time has elapsed, e.g. if you scheduled the task to run tomorrow at 13:00 at 12:00 today, a timer for 25 hours would be kicked off.

Once that scheduled activity has run, a new timer is calculated and kicked off.

If the node goes down, as soon as it comes back up, it'll work out if any scheduled tasks have been missed and if so, run them immediately. Any future dated scheduled tasks have their timers recalculated.

The best advice would be to run those errored tasks manually.